# php strnatcasecmp() erratic behaviour

Tags: php, string-comparison

I'm trying to sort an array which has alphanumeric strings with different lenghts. I'm having some difficulties with this comparison:

```
>>> strnatcasecmp("IG2349", "IG56LR1617617")
=> 1
```

As you can see, the result states that "IG2349" is greater than "IG56LR1617617", so "IG56LR1617617" appears before "IG2349" after sorting.

But taking a look at the strings, after the two first characters (equals) the third is lower on the first string than on the second string, so the result should be < 1.

This is being tested on php 5.6.20.

Answer (score 0):

Use binary safe comparison `strcasecmp` instead of natural:

```
strcasecmp("IG2349", "IG56LR1617617");
```

Comment: I know, but I need natural comparison so "G1" comes before "G10".